# Error 1195 on Windows 2012 R2 Failover Cluster with details -1

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I am unable to make error 1195 go away on my Failover Cluster.

The cluster is attempting to update the DNS entry for cluster name IP on the DNS 
server and failing with unknown error, (-1) but Event ID 1195.

Cluster log shows:

```
Network Name: [NNLIB] DNS Test success for update of XXXXXX, proceeding
Network Name: [NNLIB] Error 4294967295 on DNS DnsReplaceRecordSetW for A records, name XXXXXXXXX (ipv4Count 1, ipv6Count 0)
Network Name <Cluster Name>: Dns: Failed DNS registration with error -1 for Name: XXXXXX (Type: Singleton)e
```

I have basically reached the end of Google trying to fix this and I have given the required permissions to the cluster on DNS. I have checked Security logs in Event Veiwer. I have deleted and recreated the DNS entry multiple times.

Anyone else know what error code 4294967295  is?

Comment: The error went away on its own. As much as I am happy about this - I would love an actual explanation. I see a bunch of activity in cluster-log that doesn't make sense to me. I also see a bunch of updates - but there was no patching being done at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to recreate DNS record and check "Allow any authenticated user to update DNS records with the same owner name" during creation.

Also, specify the full domain name in DNS tab under IPv4 advanced options of the management interface on the hosts - "Append these domain suffixes"  -> Add -> domain-name.local

Comment: Allow any authenticated user to update DNS records - was done from beggining. I tried DNS suffix. No go.